# Why did I fail this review in the 'First questions' queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I have a question about [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30376889) in the *First questions* queue.

I downvoted and clicked 'other action', but it was an audit and I failed. I don't know why, because the question is closed and I think downvoting is the correct choice.

Isn't downvoting and clicking "other action" correct? Should I also raise a flag?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't VTC/Flag to Close? The question clearly has a lot to be desired. yes a downvote is likely needed, but it should most certainly also be closed.

Comment: Seems to be this (bug): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371701/unable-to-pass-first-question-first-answer-review-audits

Comment: Whew that question takes us on an adventure

Comment: Will we ever get to learn whether Alice successfully bore the bad news?? I'm on the edge of my seat!

Comment: I suspect that we'll find out in next week's instalment, @zcoop98 . Unfortunately, they OP may well then find themselves on the end of a question ban, and we won't get to read episode 3! :(

Comment: "Use downvote and click 'other action' isn't correct?" - While you might have ran into a bug, I would argue downvoting and sharing feedback is the actual proper response to that review. You can avoid failing audits by opening the question in another tab. By only downvoting the question, you are suggesting by your review actions, the question should NOT be closed.  By saying the question should not be closed, and considering the question is already deleted and/or closed, that is obviously NOT the proper response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a plain old verbatim homework assignment dump, with no effort shown whatsoever to solve the problem by themselves.

That's not the kind of question that's welcome on this site.

If you're not ready to hit "close" on that, you shouldn't be reviewing that queue.

Comment: You can click "Skip" safely, without failing the audit.

Comment: Obligatory reminder that [there is no shame in using skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/6296561)

Comment: Yeah you can skip. Or you can educate yourself. Would be nice if the audit system linked to the help center or Meta for rationale.