# How does downvoting this question fail the Review Audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I encountered this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30454823) and I downvoted the question, because come on.

Should I have flagged the question instead to satisfy the audit? (I wish we still had a "Man, this is a really craptastic question!" flag reason).

It could be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371701/unable-to-pass-first-question-first-answer-review-audits) as a possible glitch, but I just want to try and determine if downvoting was a reasonable response. If it turns out that it's not a glitch, and downvoting is no longer enough to pass an audit, then [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413154/why-did-i-fail-this-review-in-the-first-questions-queue) is probably the answer.

TBH, I don't flag nearly as many questions as I used to, because it takes longer to figure out which of the vague and obfuscated flag reasons to apply, than it did to decide that the question needed flagging in the first place. So that's why I didn't flag it for closure.

Comment: "Should I have flagged the question instead to satisfy the audit?" - Yes; Why are you only downvoting a question that should clearly be closed?

Comment: @SecurityHound I think a flag, a close-vote, or *anything* followed by "Other action" will currently fail a known bad audit in FQ. It's a reported bug.

Comment: Honestly, I'm starting to have the idea it's not a bug, and that's it's telling people that they need to vote to close questions that should be closed. I'm not sure *why* people aren't VTCing/flagging such questions in the review.

Comment: @Larnu: As I say, the current close reasons are too big of a PITA to decipher, so I don't generally flag except for duplicates. If I can't simply downvote a crappy question in FQR, then I'll just stop doing that also. The company will get what it wants, you can be sure.

Comment: Needs more Focus is the VTC/flag you wanted here, @MarkBenningfield . I disagree they are difficult to decipher as well; they have descriptions along with the reasons.

Comment: I don’t disagree the close reasons absolutely are terrible, i said as much, when they changed but not enough of the community aired their disagreement when the change happened

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't think that would have helped. Changes are made according to someone else's plan, not the wishes of the community.